# Why am I unable install Evince to a specific location on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, evince

The installable binary that Evince provides does not provide me with the option to select a location I would like it to be installed to. Instead I came across a suggestion at https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evince-list/2012-April/msg00022.html which provides a possible solution however each time I have tried it I simply get the window that displays the options provided by the command `msiexec`.

The command I am running is `msiexec.exe /i /qr "C:\Temp\apps\evince-2.32.0.145.msi" APPLICATIONFOLDER="C:\Program Files (x86)\Evince"`

I am running Windows 7 Professional as local administrator and I am using the PowerShell to run the command.

Comment: Switch /qr and /i. i parameter must be right before path to file.

Comment: @week - I did try that and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I tried just now on Windows 7 64bit.

1. Run `cmd.exe` as Administrator / eg. create shortcut on desktop for cmd.exe and click right mouse button and select `run as Administrator`
2. `cd` to folder with installator
3. `msiexec /qn /i evince-2.32.0.145.msi APPLICATIONFOLDER="c:\program files (x86)\Evince"`

If you want a setup dialog, just for confirmation, no settings there, instead of `\qn` type `\qr`. If something is not working try adding `msiexec /qn /l* evince_install.log /i ...`, that will help you solve problems and show another parameters which you can manually assign.

Comment: That worked. Question though. Why do I need to run `cmd` as an Administrator? Why can't I use the PowerShell?

Comment: I also noticed that if I attempt to uninstall the application, it removes it from the list of installed applications however does not delete the files in the directory.

Comment: You can use powershell, but powershell has a distinct semantics. Those `"` and `(` aren't good. You shouldn't run directly msiexec, but use something like http://www.i-think22.net/archives/2011/02/06/installing-multiple-msi-files-using-msiexec-exe-and-powershell/ or `invoke-expression`.. but I'm not into powershell so I don't know exactly..

Answer (score 5):

The evince msi installer has the option to select the install location. Just hit the 'Advanced' button in the opening screen.

Comment: I feel so dumb right now. Must have bypassed it about 4 times while fiddling with the CMD version in another answer. Don't forget to change from yourself to all users, then click next and specify the install location.

Answer (score 0):

It still does not work on Windows 8 ... I've been working on it for a few hours and it seems there is no issue reporting but when I go to the `Program Files (x86)` or whatever folder I place it in it just happens  to be missing (every time!).

I'm getting frustrated because I'm trying to review my technical papers compiled with PDFlatex ... is there any other software on mingw or any third party?